# Node read stream: when does the streaming happen?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, stream, fs

Here is a code example that is not much different from what you can get off the net or documentation:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var r = fs.createReadStream(process.argv[2], { encoding: 'utf8' });
r.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log("chunk: >>>" + chunk + "<<<");
});
r.on('end', function () {
    console.log("This is the end");
});
```

What puzzles me: when does the streaming that triggers events happen? Apparently not directly on construction of the read stream, because then it would be done before we get to the `on`s, and the event-listening code would never be executed (which it is, this works perfectly).

What worries me: is there a theoretical chance that an event is missed if the `on` call comes too late?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, it's not possible in node 0.10.x and later. When stream is created, it is paused, so neither `data` nor `end` events can't be emitted. When you add `data` listener (but not `end` listener), the stream is automatically resumed.

Also worth mentioning that no IO can occur before current "tick" ends, so if you attaching `data` listeners in the same tick is always safe, even for earlier node versions. For example:

```
stream.resume();
stream.on('data', ...); // <- same tick, same javascript invocation = safe

stream.resume();
setImmediate(function () {
  stream.on('data', ...); // <- different tick, different javascript invocation = unsafe
});
```

It might sound confusing, but adding listener in `process.nextTick` callback is also safe because it's actually called right after CURRENT tick before any IO callback (a case of really bad naming).

Comment: From your first paragraph, it sounds like the `'end'` event could still be lost, since the stream is resumed when I add the `'data'` listener, and might be finished before I add the `'end'` listener. I suppose what you say in the second paragraph prevents this, if both `on`s are guaranteed to be in the same tick. But what are the criteria for two statements to be executed in the same tick?

Comment: That is correct, if you add `data` listener, but not `end` listener, you might miss it. Updated the answer

Comment: What I'm still confused about is what the criteria are for two statements to be executed in the same tick. From your example, I take it that `on` doesn't make the tick end, but `setImmediate` does. So what exactly makes a tick end? I couldn't find the answer to that by googling either, although I suppose it exists in some very long and deep texts out there.

Comment: Try this: `console.log(new Error().stack)`. You will see current stack trace. When function returns, stack trace is reduced by one line (frame). When stack is empty, current tick ends.

Comment: So you're saying that no context switching takes place until the current chain of execution is completely exhausted? “Ticks” are like complete threads, executed in sequence?

Comment: I accepted this answer, since it allowed me to figure out what happened in the example. I was hoping for something more about the ticks, but I suppose I'll have to read up on it properly or ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to think of this is that all the code you've provided is blocking therefore no activity can occur on the stream until the current tick ends as vkurchatkin explains. Only when the JavaScript execution for the current tick finishes can the stream IO begin.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var r = fs.createReadStream(process.argv[2], { encoding: 'utf8' });
// Stream created in paused state, JS code is blocking IO

// We're still in the current tick so no IO could have occured since the above lines
r.on('data', function (chunk) {
  console.log("chunk: >>>" + chunk + "<<<");
});

// We're still in the current tick so no IO could have occured since the above lines
r.on('end', function () {
  console.log("This is the end");
});

// We've left the current tick so the internal IO code will now execute and call the bound events if necessary
```

Comment: But why have we left the current tick on the last line? The critical point is what triggers the tick end, if that's where the streaming begins.

Comment: When no more events you have bound are being executed. In other words, once all JS code has finished executing the next tick can happen. This may not be the perfect technical explanation but it enough to understand the concept.

Comment: “Events you have bound”, that's some more terminology I'm not familiar with. Well, I understand the concept, I'll figure out what exactly happens (including with I/O waits and timers) some other time.