# Guarantee for streams delaying flow of data

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

Node streams, from what i could find<sup>1</sup>, delay all flowing of data until the end of the tick (typically `process.nextTick`, but which queue isn't important), and don't start pumping data synchronously on method calls.

Sadly, i could not find a guarantee for this behavior in the docs (hopefully just missed it), and can therefore hardly depend on it. Is this behavior in the public API? Does this extend to all streams using the API for stream implementers?

To elaborate, except for explicitly reading sync with `stream.Readable.prototype.read`, all mechanisms appear to not synchronously start pumping data:

multiple event handlers in a row:

```
import * as stream from 'node:stream';

const r = stream.Readable.from(['my\ndata', 'more\nstuff']);
r.on('data', data => { /* do something */ });
// oops, attaching the first event handler could have already
// sent out all data synchronously
r.on('data', data => { /* do more */ });
```

starting a pipe, before the event handlers exist:

```
import * as stream from 'node:stream';
import * as readline from 'node:readline';

const r = stream.Readable.from(['my\ndata', 'more\nstuff']);
const p = new stream.PassThrough();
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: p,
  output: null,
});
r.pipe(p);
// oops, starting the pipe could have already sent all the data,
// giving "line" events without any listener being attached yet
rl.on('line', line => { /* do something */ });
```

My hope is i missed a line in the docs, and that's that. Otherwise, it will be hard to tell, how much i can depend on this behavior. E.g. in the examples above, one could explicitly pause the stream first, and resume it in `nextTick` (or similar), but it would be considerably cleaner, if this behavior could be depended upon.

---

[1]: e.g. the entire added complexity and construct of [keeping track of `sync`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/streams/readable.js#L127), or [old posts asking for the behavior at the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526515/node-read-stream-when-does-the-streaming-happen)